# Reading data from Firebase storage using firebase sdk on nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios, firebase-storage

I'm trying to:

1. list image url from node js stored in firebase storage
2. pass it as a response to a request
3. access the request from frontend react and store it in an array
   state
4. pass it into img src

But the img is not being displayed.

The backend code:

```
admin.initializeApp({
  credential:admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  storageBucket:'bucket name'
})
const bucket = admin.storage().bucket()
async function getImageURLsFromFolder(folderPath) {
  const [files] = await bucket.getFiles({
    prefix: folderPath
  });

  const imageURLs = [];

  for (const file of files) {
    const [url] = await file.getSignedUrl({
      action: 'read',
      expires: '03-01-2500'
    });

    imageURLs.push(url);
  }

  return imageURLs;
}
```

The React side code

```
const [srcUrl,setSrcUrl] = useState([]);
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {  
  const fetchData = async ()=>{
    try{
     await axios.get('http://localhost:8080/items').then((response)=>{
       setData(response.data.dbData);
       setSrcUrl(response.data.urlList)
       console.log(response);
       console.log(srcUrl);
      })
    }catch(e){
      console.log(e);
    }
  }
  
  fetchData()
}, []);
)
```

Comment: If you inspect the missing img, what actually is the HTML for `src`?